# Why isn't this loop working? It only changes the value of a but never changes the values of b, c, or d

Tags: loops

```
a=0
b=0
c=0
d=0
mylist=[-1,2,3,-4,3,-9,-3]
for k in range(len(mylist)-1):
                    if mylist[k] > 0:
                        if mylist[k+1]>0:
                            a+=1
                        elif mylist[k+1]<0:
                            b+=1
                    elif mylist[k] < 0:
                        if mylist[k+1]>0:
                            c+=1
                        elif mylist[k+1]<0:
                            d+=1
```

I have this code within a function that prints out the values of a, b, c, and d. The values of those variables are meant to change based on whether the previous variable in mylist is above or below zero.

But it only changes the value of a. I can't for the life of me figure out why.

Comment: It *does* change b c and d.

Comment: Just to clarify, this is Python, correct? Your question should always be tagged with the language you are writing in.

Comment: right this is python

Comment: Looks like the code under `for k in range(len(mylist)-1):` is indented 20 spaces. The code still runs correctly. Even so, you don't need so much indentation... 4 spaces is enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

But it works well:

```py
a=0
b=0
c=0
d=0
mylist=[-1,2,3,-4,3,-9,-3]
for k in range(len(mylist)-1):
    if mylist[k] > 0:
        if mylist[k+1]>0:
            a+=1
        elif mylist[k+1]<0:
            b+=1
    elif mylist[k] < 0:
        if mylist[k+1]>0:
            c+=1
        elif mylist[k+1]<0:
            d+=1

print((a,b,c,d))
```

Output:

```
(1, 2, 2, 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I copied and pasted the code on my machine. Seems to be working fine
The values of a,b,c and d at the end are `1,2,2,1`